# Write a program that prints a program that's almost quine

Tags: code-golf, quine

Your task is to make a program in `L` that takes `n` as an input number, output a program `p` in `L` that prints its own first `n` characters.

### Rules

- The program `p` has to be irreducible, See an example below.
- **PAY ATTENTION TO THIS RULE:** If a program takes an input as `n`, the first `n` characters of the output  would be the same as the first `n` characters of the program taking `n + 1` as input.
- Standard loopholes apply
- You have to make a full program.
- A trailing newline of the output of the program `p` is allowed if the first `n` characters of the program `p` doesn't have a newline

### Example

I'm using pseudocode as `L`

if `n` = 10, an example of `p` would be

```
PRINT "PRINT \"PRI"
```

but not

```
// comment
PRINT "// comment"
```

because it breaks the first rule above (if you removed `com` and still makes the same output).

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so you have to make your program shortest as possible (in bytes).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 1 byte

```
Ｎ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9nnX//5sAAA) Port of @Ausername's Vyxal answer. Explanation: Simply outputs `n` `-`s; strings of printable ASCII need no delimiter in Charcoal, so as a program, it just prints the string of `-`s, i.e. itself.

Answer (score 6):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>20</s> 18 bytes

```raku
say 1 x get,".put"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVLBUKFCIT21REdJr6C0ROn/f1MA)

Outputs a number with `n` digits followed by a `.put`

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 48 bytes

```python
print('a'*int(input())+'=1;print(locals()[-1])')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQz1RXQtEZ@YVlJZoaGpqq9saWkOkcvKTE3OKNTSjdQ1jNdU1//83BQA)

Comment: `locals()` is a `dict`, so this gives a `KeyError`. Perhaps `print([*locals()][-1])` would be better.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
\1*
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJcXDEqIiwiIiwiNCJd)
Literally prints that many 1s.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 13 bytes

```
.+
*KKK
KK
K`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0@bS8vb25sLhBL@/zcBAA) Explanation: Outputs a string of length `n+2` alternating between `K` and `` ` ``. This creates a program in Retina that outputs the part of the string after the `` K` `` which is also equal to the first `n` characters of the program. Retina can also execute the resulting program for you automatically: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvpFSn4Z7wX0@bS8vb25sLhBL@/zcBAA) Or see both the program and its output: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvpFQXo@Ge8F9Pm0vL29ubC4QS/v83AQA)

Comment: I don't think the resulting program is irreducable, since you can just delete the leading `_` with the same output

Comment: @Sisyphus Thanks, I've come up with a new approach now.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 26 bytes

```ruby
$><<?1*gets.to_i+'=>x;p x'
```

Uses the Ruby 3 pattern match syntax to bind the integer to `x`.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboWu1TsbGzsDbXSU0uK9Ury4zO11W3tKqwLFCrUIQqg6hYsNIUwAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
1¸sиJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f8NCO4gs7vP7/NwUA)

Sort-of port of [emanresu A's Vyxal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/255303/114446):

```python
1¸sиJ  # Implicit input                 STACK:
1¸     # Push ['1']                     ['1'], 5
  sи   # Repeat input number of times   ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
    J  # Join by ''                     '11111'
       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 36 bytes

```julia
print('1'^parse(Int,ARGS[]),|>,show)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v6AoM69EQ91QPa4gsag4VcMzr0THMcg9ODpWU6fGTqc4I79c8////6YA)

port of [Jo King's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/255304/98541)

will print something like `1111|>show` (equivalent to `show(1111)`)

Answer (score 0):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 65 bytes

```
/9/8*//8/7*//7/6*//6/5*//5/4*//4/3*//3/2*//2/1*//1/0*//*0/9*//0//
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcwpDsAwDAVR3qOEjJ3VOU5BpYKy3F/uJ2/YnO8@73OSC5JNFAiWXEw5GXLQZafJRpUVl47JYmzFdPDIHw)

Converts decimal to unary.

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 0 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf6vz6Wv//@/Fgb4DwA)

Takes input as unary. For me, That's cheating.

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 25 bytes

```bash
eval echo\ echo\$_{0..$1}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kKbE4Y8GCpaUlaboWO1PLEnMUUpMz8mMgpEp8tYGenophLUQeqmxptJKpUiyUAwA)